# how to implement/Handle auto bidding using laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue, laravel-jobs

I am currently in the process of building a online auction website  with similar features like in `Mytokuri.in / Bidderboy.com` . My website is complete around 90% complete. I face an obstacle of creating or building an auto bidding system handled at the server, since auto bidding has to happen even if the user is logged out or in hibernate . The auto bidding will run upto a given threshold limit and end automatically. I thought of using queues to achieve it. When I am going to use queues there are some difficulties and issues in the application that i feel in it, I have the following scenario

```
   - 'N' products with 'N' bidders and 'N' auto bidding jobs , One job for one product
```

I planned to create a job in laravel and run it if not already exists, and make the job to bid for the user for given threshold limit. I want to know is it efficient or is there any better solution is there to implement auto bidding

Comment: You don't need queues, you just need a scheduled task to continually check for and process active autobidders on users that aren't currently winning a live auction. Having built a site exactly like this a long time ago, you'll also find you need to implement bidding inside the persistence layer to ensure bids are processed in order during periods of high traffic, particularly when an auction is ending.

Comment: @kungphu Thanks for the tip, please can you give an example code base for the sheduled task , Right now I Have a table to track list of users using  auto bidding . I use it to execute the bid in an order , And I also can you please explain "implement bidding inside the persistence layer", and when it scales how to split the task or schedule it without duplicating it

Comment: Sorry, for that I'd need access to your code, a lot of free time, and a contract at a pretty good rate. You're basically asking for someone to implement this for you; that's just not going to happen.

Comment: @kungphu Sorry for the misunderstanding as you said i am going to shedule a task , when in comes to 10,000 Auctions and lets say I have minimum of 30 auto bidders per auction and I am going to schedule one task I am sure It will be a time lag there for sure, Concern is about the lag and splitting the task between nodes, I am exactly not asking for a code but a  tip would be help full